# django ckeditor generating thumbnail from uploaded image

Tags: django, ckeditor

Hello I'm using ckeditor now as I heard this gives more control. but I read the documentation and it's pretty much like other editors. Does anyone know if we can generate thumbnails from user uploaded image in ckeditor? I know thumbnails are generated in ckeditor upload gallery but I want to use the thumbnail image in the index page.           `{{ post.content|safe }}` includes image and context as well since I'm using ckeditor. I want to use post.image in the index page, Is there any way I can achieve this?